# Run JS in iOS webView every time loading a new page

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

For example, I want to run this part of code every time user click a new link in my UIWebView,

```
NSString* js =
@"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); "
"meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); "
"meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width;initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0' ); "
"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
```

how can I do that? which API should I look at?
And I want this JS run in new page. How should I determine if the new page is fully loaded? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things likely to go wrong in this scenario: **1)** your Js throws an exception and **2)** the page reloads *after* your Js has run, and therefore reset the effects of your script.

In my experience, when a Javascript doesn't seem to run in a `UIWebView`, it's almost always the Javascript that is throwing an exception.

Try surrounding the script in `try { ... } catch { ... }` to capture the exception:

```
NSString* js =
@"try {"
"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); "
  // [rest of the script...]
"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";
" } catch (exc) { "
" window.ERR = exc.toString(); "
" } "
```

Now you can set a breakpoint in Xcode after your call to `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`. An error message might be available if you run

```
po [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.ERR"]
```

In your debug prompt.

A good idea when you try out Javascript on your `UIWebView` is to first do exploratory 
work in something like the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to weed out the worst errors (e.g. syntax errors). If your code works there, the next step is to connect to the view using
Safaris [Web inspector for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html) and see if it still does what it should.

@nilveryboring's point that you add scripts in `webViewDidFinishLoading` rather than in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is correct. In `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` the page hasn't been loaded yet, and any state you introduce at that point will be discarded by the loading page.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when the user clicks a link with:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Once you have detected that he has clicked on a link, perform your js.

More on it in the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a).

Comment: The JS dont run in new page. How should I determine if the new page is fully loaded?

Comment: @nilveryboring That is all part of the [UIWebView delegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). To detect when a UIWebView did finish loading, you use `webViewDidFinishLoading`. As to why the js snippet is not running, I am not exactly sure (I don't know jscript). Set some breakpoints to see if it is being called. Other than that, check the jscript code and the conversion to NSString to make sure you are doing it right. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @nilveryboring, do you need to open another question for this? Do you want to edit your question?